# Where can I get the device profile for Xperia Active so that I can use it within Flash Builder?

Tags: android, flash-builder, device, profile, sony

Where can I get the device profile for Xperia Active so that I can emulate it within Flash Builder? Can anyone point me to where I can download it? I'm not sure if this question should be here but I took my chances anyway since it's still related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out how, I just made the profile myself. Thanks anyway.